# Why is the computer clock off by few seconds after reboot?

Tags: ntp, chrony

My computer runs 24/7 and does an automatic reboot at night after each kernel/systemd/glibc upgrade. On Fedora this happens every few days.

The system clock is synchronized with NTP protocol using the `chrony`. The HW clock is synchronized:

```
# Enable kernel synchronization of the real-time clock (RTC).
rtcsync
```

and normally I see no difference between system time and HW clock.

But after a reboot:

```
28.02.2021 00:34:08.657 chronyd: System clock wrong by -4.021024 seconds
```

or this night:

```
mar 02 01:48:18 chronyd[990]: chronyd exiting
mar 02 01:48:18 systemd[1]: Stopped NTP client/server.
-- Reboot --
mar 02 01:49:37 systemd[1]: Starting NTP client/server...
mar 02 01:49:37 chronyd[989]: chronyd version 4.0 starting (+CMDMON +NTP +REFCLOCK +RTC +PRIVDROP +SCFILTER +SIGND +ASYNCDNS +NTS +SECHASH +IPV6 +DEBUG)
mar 02 01:49:37 chronyd[989]: Frequency -13.026 +/- 0.008 ppm read from /var/lib/chrony/drift
mar 02 01:49:37 chronyd[989]: Using right/UTC timezone to obtain leap second data
mar 02 01:49:37 systemd[1]: Started NTP client/server.
mar 02 01:49:51 chronyd[989]: Selected source 162.159.200.123 (hu.pool.ntp.org)
mar 02 01:49:51 chronyd[989]: Time smoothing activated (leap seconds only)
mar 02 01:49:51 chronyd[989]: System clock wrong by -9.232765 seconds
mar 02 01:49:42 chronyd[989]: System clock was stepped by -9.232765 seconds
```

If I manually stop the `chrony`, wait 2 minutes and restart it, nothing bad happens (as expected).

I searched the net a lot and read many posts, but still cannot understand what I'm doing wrong.

UPDATE, output of `timedatectl`:

```
               Local time: St 2021-03-03 14:11:27 CET    
           Universal time: St 2021-03-03 13:11:27 UTC    
                 RTC time: St 2021-03-03 13:11:27        
                Time zone: Europe/Bratislava (CET, +0100)
System clock synchronized: yes                           
              NTP service: active                        
          RTC in local TZ: no
```

Output of `hwclock --verbose`:

```
hwclock from util-linux 2.36.1
System Time: 1614784382.362288
Trying to open: /dev/rtc0
Using the rtc interface to the clock.
Assuming hardware clock is kept in UTC time.
Waiting for clock tick...
...got clock tick
Time read from Hardware Clock: 2021/03/03 15:13:03
Hw clock time : 2021/03/03 15:13:03 = 1614784383 seconds since 1969
Time since last adjustment is 1614784383 seconds
Calculated Hardware Clock drift is 0.000000 seconds
2021-03-03 16:13:02.344795+01:00
```

`systemd-timesyncd` is disabled and inactive.

Comment: *Wild guess*: The battery of the computer's hardware clock is tired or empty. The clock gets no power for a short while when the computer reboots, thus the delay. If you can afford a few minutes down time, switch the box off for the time of a coffee and see if the delay is several minutes. CAVEAT: I have no idea if my musings have any resemblance with reality.

Comment: And I don't think you are doing anything wrong. NTP was created precisely to compensate for such problems. Reliable hardware clocks are not necessarily a huge priority for hardware designers.

Comment: @Philip Couling Is says that Fedora is used. So, there is no `dpkg`, but `rpm` or `yum` or `dnf`. However, systemd-timesyncd RPM package is available for Fedora, too.

Comment: @berndbausch I don't suspect a battery problem. It is a backup battery, the computer is powered all the time and BIOS settings in the CMOS are not lost.

Comment: @PhilipCouling The `systemd-timesyncd` does not provide time to other computers on the local network. I have to stick with `chrony` deamon.

Comment: @nobody oops, yes I missed it was fedora. but effectivly the same question.

Comment: @VPfB I wasn't referring to other computers on the same network.  `systemd-timesyncd` can ship with some distributions so I was suggesting you double check to see if it's installed on the same system that has the problem even if it has no configured NTP servers.  I've reformed my answer to explain why.

Comment: @PhilipCouling I checked, It is installed, but disabled. I have even checked that the file `/var/lib/systemd/timesync/clock` does not exsit, not even the directory.

Answer (score 0):

Try command

```
timedatectl
```

to see if RTC clock is ever adjusted, or is off the whole time. You can also use `hwclock` or similar commands.

For the ntpd service, which is now being deprecated and replaced in many newer distributions, I know that it wrote a drift file on the disk on shutdown, and set the HW clock to the correct time. In the drift file, there were information about system clock accuracy, shutdown time, etc. When you switched on the computer ntpd would check the drift file, and adjusted the system clock according to recorded drift to synchronize quicker.

`chrony` synchronizes much quicker than ntpd, as that is a need for more and more virtual machines, that do now have a hardware clock. I wonder if chrony adjusts the HW clock on shutdown. Maybe you should check if the discrepancy is only growing. In that case it would be sensible to set HW clock at least on shutdown or see why the system does not adjust HW clock.

Maybe there is some HW problem. I had the strangest case some years ago, when a computer's time was off for about 17 seconds in one minute. The problem was to many HW interrupts, for which I first suspected some special PCI card. It turned out that KVM switch supported some kind of sound via USB, where keyboard and mouse were transferred, too. Without that KVM switch everything worked fine.

Comment: Thank you for you answer, I will go throug your suggestions. So far I checked that `/var/lib/chrony/drift` exists and is less than an hour old. I deleted `/etc/adjtime` some time ago. it was not updated for months. It did not help.

Comment: @Philip Couling You are right. System clock drift is recorded in drift file in order to perform quicker snychronization after reboot. I have corrected the answer. Thanks for the correction.